# Problem with small fluid inflow

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a kitchen scene where everything was modeled using real world values(metric) and I wanted to make the tap run some water.

But for some weird reason the Inflow object that is the size of the tap's hole is not giving me a continuous stream of water. It is instead just dropping a few droplets like big giant particles. I've bumped the resolution up to 200 and nothing seems to change.

What's causing this?

Comment: Did you applied scale to inflow object?

Comment: Yes I did. I also tought it was that, but after rebaking it, the result was the same. :\

Comment: Blender fluid simulation si not very good for small scale simulations like this, and also for for large scale simulations (ocean, waterfalls etc.) You can try  molecular addon or fluid particles with cubesurfer addon created by PyroEvil. You can also search for DualSPhysics - but this looks more complicated for use. Be honest, I never used what I recommend now, I know all this only for from YT and I hope this can be solution for you.

Comment: That's what i thought. Thanks for the info. :(